# How is SFS partition different than other?

Tags: partitioning

i have SFS partitions. how this partition is different than other linux partition? can it be converted to other and vice versa without losing data?

```
aneal@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x97646c29

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1        1531    12290016+  42  SFS
/dev/sda2   *        1531        1543      102400   42  SFS
/dev/sda3            1543       14070   100618240   42  SFS
/dev/sda4           14070       38914   199559512   42  SFS

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 3965 MB, 3965190144 bytes
49 heads, 48 sectors/track, 3292 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 2352 * 512 = 1204224 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/mmcblk0p1   *           4        3293     3868160    b  W95 FAT32
```

Answer (score 2):

These are dynamic disks, fairly common with Win 7. Usually if you try to create a 5th partition it offers to convert to dynamic. What it means is that you could have other partitions not shown in the MBR partition table (that Ubuntu won't see).

Check this out for some options for converting back: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1692248

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Id number of 42 I think you'll find it's a **Secure File System**, see information at [this link](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/partitions/partition_types-1.html)

Did you choose to encrypt the partition when you installed Ubuntu?

You can re-install Ubuntu and choose another partition type;

[image: Allocate Drive Space]

Though you will more than likely be asked to reformat the partition and loose any data currently on it so back it up first!!

Comment: i did install ubuntu inside win7.  i dont think i was asked to chose about the partition.

Comment: Are you saying this is a WUBI install?? you cannot modify the file system structure if this is the case and you will not be able to install burg to manage your boot loader.......

Answer (score 0):

SFS

As a file system for short, is better for remote control of files that are not stored locally to access them without any special privilegies.

it' is different from other as it is distributed file system, which is accessed over a computer network.
[Wikipedia](http://www.google.com.mx/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBIQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-certifying_File_System&ei=n93ITZafKObr0QHPmZySCQ&usg=AFQjCNGYf0RdhporE6w40Njx2rBF3RwuMw)